# Google Analytics Adwords data stored lifelong?

Tags: google-analytics, google-ads-api

Does someone know how long Google will store the data from the Analytics/Adwords etc. accounts? Can't find it anywhere, and also can't believe they will store it like forever. It would be nice to see in 30 years for example, how many visitors I had in 2010.

Comment: *bump* Contacted Apple, they had no clear answer.

Answer (score 0):

Google usually won't delete your account or the data within your account. However, there are exceptions:

- Google may close down your whole Google account if you severely violate the terms of service.  This might even happen by accident. See [complaints on google help forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topicsearch/deleted$20terms$20of$20service$20violations).
- Regarding AdWords, Google started to [delete unused entities](https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/6172751?hl=en) in March 2015. ("we’ll only delete entities that never accrued impressions and have been removed for more than 100 days.")

There is no guarantee that Google will store your data lifelong (who knows if internet or Google still exists in 30 years?), but is highly unlikely that Google will delete it. I have seen AdWords account that haven't been used since 2005 and still all data has been there.